# How does the function g(x) behave as x tends to 1?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, limits-and-convergence

Suppose $g:[0,1)→R$ is a continuous function satisfying
   $g(x^2)=x−g(x)$

for every x on interval $[0,1)$.

How does the function g(x) behave as x tends to 1?

Comment: Emm Tends to 0.5?

Comment: Obviously, if there is a limit, then it has to be 1/2.  One can prove that $g(x)=\sum_k(-1)^kx^{2^k}$.  I think that this is nondecreasing and tends to $1/2$ as $x\to 1$, but it does not seem to be trivial to prove that.

Comment: @NeilStrickland That can't be the only solution, given that the homogeneous form $g(x^2) = -g(x)$ has nontrivial solutions, of the form $\sum_n c_n cos((2n + 1) \pi log_2(-ln(x)) + d_n sin((2n + 1) \pi log_2(-ln(x))$.

Comment: @user44191 Your functions are not continuous at $x=0$.  For example, if $g(x)=\cos(\pi\log_2(-\ln(x)))$ then we can consider $a_n=\exp(-2^n)$ and $a_n\to 0$ with $g(a_n)=(-1)^n$.  If  $g(x)=-g(x^2)$ then $g(x)=g(x^{2^{2k}})$ and $x^{2^{2k}}\to 0$, so if $g$ is continuous then $g(x)=g(0)$.  Also, the identity $g(x)=-g(x^2)$ gives $g(0)=0$.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Ah, of course, was so focused on 1 that I forgot about 0. The periodic function I derived my homogeneous solution must converge as it goes to $\infty$, so it must be constant, and the only solution is $g(x) = 0$.

Comment: I think, it is quite a normal and not trivial question.

Comment: Wait... this problem seems *very* familiar, and with a somewhat surprising solution. (My memory could be deceiving me, but for some reason Noam Elkies comes to mind as having discussed this (?!))

Comment: Don't know if this is of interest to you, but if you instead require $g:(0,1]\rightarrow {\Bbb R}$ continuous then there is a solution that behaves like $g(x)=\frac12 - \frac13 \ln(x) + O((\ln x)^2)$ as $x\rightarrow 1$ but this solution does not extend continuously to $x=0$

Answer (score 9):

This appears as Problem 4 of an [MSRI Emissary publication](https://www.msri.org/attachments/media/news/emissary/2004-02.pdf), and indeed this problem has been discussed by Noam Elkies. See also his web page (problem 8 [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/index.html)), where he links to a solution.

The conclusion is that $g(x)$ has no limit as $x$ approaches $1$; it starts off monotone increasing until you get pretty close to $1$, but one finds $g(.995) \approx .50088 > 1/2$. Note that $g(x) = x - x^2 + g(x^4) > g(x^4)$, so one concludes there are infinitely many points where $g(x) > 1/2$. But as already observed, if a limit exists, it would have to be $1/2$; therefore no limit exists.

In fact one finds that $g$ oscillates more and more quickly as $x$ approaches $1$, each oscillation occurring about 4 times more quickly than the previous.